# Changing a global variable from outside in a Flask based Python web application

Tags: python, global-variables, flask

I do not understand how to change a global variable when using the flask extension flask-script. To demonstrate my problem I developed the following small flask application, which will increase a global counter variable for every request call. In addition it offers a reset function to reset the global counter:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.script import Manager
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

manager = Manager(app)

counter = 0

@manager.command
@app.route("/reset")
def reset():
    global counter
    print "Counter before reset:", counter
    counter = 0
    print "Counter after reset:", counter
    return str(counter) 

@app.route("/")
def add():
    global counter
    print "Counter before adding:", counter
    counter +=1
    print "Counter after adding:", counter
    return str(counter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

I start my flask application using `python counter.py runserver`

When I access the address 127.0.0.1:5000 I see the counter increasing

```
Counter before adding: 0
Counter after adding: 1
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2013 10:09:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2013 10:09:35] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
Counter before adding: 1
Counter after adding: 2
...
```

When I access the address 127.0.0.1:5000/reset I see that the counter is reset

```
Counter before reset: 4
Counter after reset: 0
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2013 10:10:39] "GET /reset HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2013 10:10:39] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

However when I try to call the reset method from the command line using the manage interface provided by the flask-script extension the global counter variable is not reset:

```
> python counter.py reset
Counter before reset: 0
Counter after reset: 0
0
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I access and manipulate a global variable using flask-script?

Answer (score 7):

Python global variables like `counter` live in operating system process memory space. Each started and stopped process (application, command, etc.) gets its own pie of memory.

When you run `python counter.py reset` it starts a new process with its own memory space and variables. The variable reset is run against this process, not the process running the web server.

To correctly reset the variable

- Keep variable out of process memory space (E.g. in memcached, database)
- Create a command which calls the web server process via a special view URL using wget, curl, urllib or such and this view resets the variable inside the process memory space

Comment: So is there no easy way (without DB, memcache) to fix my example?